# NEST V7.12.1 - Self referencing loop detected for property 'response' with type 'Elasticsearch.Net.ApiCallDetails'

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am fairly new to ElasticSearch and I am currently trying it out for work, however when trying to make an Regex Query, it gives the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'response' with type 'Elasticsearch.Net.ApiCallDetails'. Path 'apiCall.originalException'.
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
> ......

The query:

```
var ChildFileItems = ElasticClient.Search<FileData>(s => s
                //.From(0).Size(10)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Regexp(r => r
                        .Field(p => p.FilePath)
                        //.Value($"/{SearchPath}\\\\([A-Z a-z0-9_.-]+)[.]([A-Z a-z0-9]+)/g")
                        .Value(@$"/([A-Z a-z:0-9_.\\-]+)/g")
                    )
                )
            );
```

(I am just trying to get any Regex Query working).
When I perform a Regex query which does not find any results, it gives no error, so it is (I would guess) something within my object. Online I have found that you can Ignore this Error, however these were all for version 6, and I cannot get it working within version 7. This is the best (Read: I get no errors) version, however with this I still get the error.

When I perform a "normal" match query, it does however work fine and I get my results back.

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, (builtInSerializer, connectionSettings) =>
                new JsonNetSerializer(builtInSerializer, connectionSettings, () => new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                }))
                .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p)
                .PrettyJson();
            ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is strange; it's a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`, but the 7.12.1 client doesn't use Newtonsoft.Json internally.

A serializer that uses Newtonsoft.Json can be configured with `JsonNetSerializer` as per your second code example, but this serializer is used to deserialize your documents, and wouldn't be used to deserialize `Elasticsearch.Net.ApiCallDetails`, which is a low level client type.

I tried to replicate the error with Nest 7.12.1 but am not able to. There are a couple of problems with the regular expression however;

1. The enclosing `/` and `g` modifier are not valid or supported by [the regular expression engine](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html) and can be omitted.
2. Since the regex value is a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim), the `\\` is the literal `\\\\` when sent in the query, which results in an error:

```js
// Request
POST http://localhost:9200/default_index/_search?pretty=true&typed_keys=true 
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "FilePath": {
        "value": "/([A-Z a-z:0-9_.\\\\-]+)/g"
      }
    }
  }
}

// Response
Status: 400

{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "query_shard_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to create query: expected ']' at position 24",
        "index_uuid" : "83Lsg5kRR32c6iSK-1L5rw",
        "index" : "default_index"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "default_index",
        "node" : "1k1iMRXORXSEKvOH4Iz46Q",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "query_shard_exception",
          "reason" : "failed to create query: expected ']' at position 24",
          "index_uuid" : "83Lsg5kRR32c6iSK-1L5rw",
          "index" : "default_index",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "expected ']' at position 24"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

3. I think the `.` also needs to be escaped (otherwise is a match for any character).

Putting all together, here's a working example

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "default_index";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri($"http://localhost:9200"));
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, JsonNetSerializer.Default)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
        .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p)
        // The following settings are useful during development but come
        // with overhead and so likely don't want them in production.
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
        .PrettyJson()
        .OnRequestCompleted(callDetails =>
        {
            // Added this so that you can see the requests/responses to and
            // from Elasticsearch.

            if (callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                var jObjects = new List<JObject>();
                using (var sr = new StringReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes)))
                using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    jsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
                    while (jsonTextReader.Read())
                        jObjects.Add((JObject)JObject.ReadFrom(jsonTextReader));
                }
                
                var formatting =  jObjects.Count == 1 
                    ? Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented 
                    : Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None;
                var json = string.Join("\n", jObjects.Select(j => j.ToString(formatting)));
                
                Console.WriteLine($"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri} \n{json}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri}");
            }
    
            Console.WriteLine();
    
            if (callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                         $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                         $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                         $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
            }
        });
        
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.Indices.Exists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.Indices.Delete(defaultIndex);
    
    client.Bulk(b => b
        .Index(defaultIndex)
        .IndexMany(new [] {
            new FileData { FilePath = "Foo.jpg" },
            new FileData { FilePath = "^$%*#@" },
        })
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );
    
    var searchResponse = client.Search<FileData>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Regexp(r => r
                .Field(p => p.FilePath)
                .Value(@"([A-Z a-z:0-9_\.\-]+)")
            )
        )
    );
}

public class FileData 
{
    public string FilePath {get;set;}
}
```

which finds the document with file path `Foo.jpg`

Comment: That seems too work yeah!
I did test it myself a bit as well, and I do get the error due to the Regex not working, since with your code I do not get the error with/without setting the JsonNetSerializer. Thank you very much :)